# Digitally signing objects with CryptoJS approach?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptography, cryptojs

I just want to see whether I'm doing this right.  [I have created a stackblitz demo here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cryptojs).

I want to digitally sign objects.  I think the way to do it is:

1) Create the object

```
const o = { title: 'All dogs go to heaven', publishDate: new Date(),
```

2) JSON.stringify it with a canonical json implementation

```
const s = stringify(o); //canonical json implementation of stringify
```

3) Pass it through CryptoJS Hmac256 and Base64 functions like this:

```
console.log(enc.Base64.stringify(HmacSHA256(s, 'secret')));
```

I think this should work for any object right?  (Regardless of whether it's a simple object like the one here an object containing application state that could be megabytes in size.)

Part of the reason I ask is that this [Auth0 article](https://jwt.io/introduction/) produces the signaure like this:

```
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  secret)
```

Which inverts the order of the function calls (Calls HMACSHA256 last).

Comment: "Canonical JSON means that the same object should always be stringified to the exact same string. JavaScripts native JSON.stringify does not guarantee any order for object keys when serializing". So it is fine to sign JSON as a text file, but if you serialize JSON then a different platform or even JavaScript version may produce different JSON, and the signature may not verify. So you have to verify the JSON string *before* parsing it.

Comment: Do you know if there's an NPM package that gets us around that?

Comment: That was a quote from a Github page that offers canonical JSON, so yeah :P

Comment: Cool - This one looks pretty promising: https://www.npmjs.com/package/canonical-json     If anyone know of a better package please post comments.

Comment: Updated the stackblitz to use the canoncial json implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-cryptojs